# Get all repetitions starting the same appearing in a row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Is there any way to translate the following query

```
select word
from string1 
where Left(word, 1) in (
     select Left(word, 1) as firstInitial 
     from string1 
     group by Left(word , 1)
     having count(*) > 1
)
```

into LINQ  so when you run it on   "While Kim kept kicking I ate my Dunkin donut with great gusto" it produces something like

```
(miss,Match,Match,Match,miss,miss,miss,Match,Match,miss,Match,Match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution shows one possible approach. To use this, be sure to add the [`MoreLINQ` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) to your project.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MoreLinq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "While Kim kept kicking I ate my Dunkin donut with great gusto";

            var value = input.Split(' ');

            var lagged = value.Lag(1, (current, previous) => new { current = current?.ToLowerInvariant(), previous = previous?.ToLowerInvariant() });
            var leaded = value.Lead(1, (current, next) => new { next = next?.ToLowerInvariant() });

            var results = lagged.Zip(leaded, (x, y) => x.current?.FirstOrDefault() == x.previous?.FirstOrDefault() ||
                                                       x.current?.FirstOrDefault() == y.next?.FirstOrDefault());

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the code splits the string into multiple words, and then looks at each word (`current`) and the word before (`previous`) and after (`next`) it. It then compares the first letter of `current` vs that of `previous` and `next`.

If you want to return `1` / `0` rather than `true` / `false` then change just this line of code:

```
var results = lagged.Zip(leaded, (x, y) => (x.current?.FirstOrDefault() == x.previous?.FirstOrDefault() ||
                                            x.current?.FirstOrDefault() == y.next?.FirstOrDefault()) ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mjwills.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this won't be as simple as a few lines, but I can try:

First, the simplest but not so elegant `for` loop method:

```
var words = string1.Split(' ').ToList();
string[] results = new string[words.Count];    //edited: can use .Count instead of .Count()
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == words.Count - 1)
        results[i] = char.ToLower(words[i - 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0]) ? "Match" : "miss";
    else if (i == 0)
        results[i] = char.ToLower(words[i + 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0]) ? "Match" : "miss";
    else
    {
        bool leftMatch = char.ToLower(words[i - 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0]);
        bool rightMatch = char.ToLower(words[i + 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0]);
        results[i] = (leftMatch || rightMatch) ? "Match" : "miss";
    }
}
```

What this does is go through each element, if the left or right word has a same initial character, it is a "Match", otherwise it is "miss". For the first and last word it just needs to check one neighbor instead of 2.

Using [Enumerable.Range Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) of LINQ, as well as the [?: Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), this can be simplified into a few lines:

```
var words = string1.Split(' ').ToList();
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, words.Count).Select(i => i == words.Count - 1 ?
        char.ToLower(words[i - 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0]) ? "Match" : "miss" :
        i == 0 ?
        char.ToLower(words[i + 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0]) ? "Match" : "miss" :
        (char.ToLower(words[i - 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0]) || char.ToLower(words[i + 1][0]) == char.ToLower(words[i][0])) ? "Match" : "miss" ).ToList();
```

The `ToList()` at the end is optional, you can convert `ToArray()` if you wish.

Comment: Both give me an error:  Cs0121 c# the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties and
The problem is that you make an integer division (results also in an int) and a int can be implicitly converted to both double and decimal. Therefore, you need to make sure the expression results in one of those; double is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Keyur PATEL. Nice solutions too. I am learning a lot from you, guys. Great site!!